# Import XML file to Access

Tags: xml, ms-access, import

I need to import an XML file to an Access database.

I try `Application.ImportXML` but the structure of the file is wrong.
After import I have 3 tables, but main table FormattedReportObject has structure:

> "ObjectName"  "FormattedValue" "Value"

I need to create a table with structure:

> "Tytul" "z1Lpf1" "z1Iloscf1" "z1KodKreskowyf1" "z1SymbolTowaruf1"

Values for this structure are in column FormattedValue.

[Link to my website](http://kumcio.cba.pl/546kopia.xml)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language designed to transform XML files. Since your original XML will not import in needed structure, you need to transform original XML to extract the data needed.

Specifically, you have to pass the *ObjectName* text as new XML elements in order to migrate as columns in Access table. Also, XSLT filters to only the details section of XML which maintain full complete data without any empty columns and rows.

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl file, a special fully valid .xml file to be loaded in VBA)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                              xmlns:doc="urn:crystal-reports:schemas"
                              exclude-result-prefixes="doc">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" encoding="utf-8"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/doc:FormattedReport">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="descendant::doc:FormattedReportObjects[doc:FormattedReportObject/doc:ObjectName='z1Lpf1']"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:FormattedReportObjects">
    <xsl:element name="data" namespace="urn:crystal-reports:schemas">      
        <xsl:apply-templates select="doc:FormattedReportObject"/>      
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="doc:FormattedReportObject">  
    <xsl:element name="{doc:ObjectName}" namespace="urn:crystal-reports:schemas">
        <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(doc:Value|doc:TextValue)"/>
    </xsl:element>      
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**VBA**

```vb
Public Sub XMLImportData()
    ' ADD MSXML, v6.0 REFERENCE UNDER TOOLS
    Dim xmlDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60 
    Dim xslDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Dim newDoc As New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

    ' LOAD XML AND XSL FILES
    xmlDoc.async = False
    xmlDoc.Load "http://kumcio.cba.pl/546kopia.xml"

    xslDoc.async = False
    xslDoc.Load "C:\Path\To\XSLT_Script.xsl"

    ' TRANSFORM XML
    xmlDoc.transformNodeToObject xslDoc, newDoc
    newDoc.Save "C:\Path\To\OutputXML.xml"

    Application.ImportXML "C:\Path\To\OutputXML.xml"

    Set xmlDoc = Nothing: Set xslDoc = Nothing: Set newDoc = Nothing
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FormattedReport xmlns="urn:crystal-reports:schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance">
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>1.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>1.17003Świetlik 4,5 x 39 ziel</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>100.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>szt.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767311281</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382378</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>50</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>1.17003</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>2.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>1.17004Świetlik 4,5 x 39 czer</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>100.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>szt.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767311298</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382381</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>50</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>1.17004</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>3.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>1.17005Świetlik 4,5 x 39 nieb</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>100.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>szt.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767311304</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382386</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>50</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>1.17005</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>4.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.01015Gł.jig 7g hacz 3/0</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767315227</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382189</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.01015</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>5.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.01013Gł.jig 7g hacz 1/0</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767315203</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382177</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.01013</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>6.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.02017Głowka jigowa micro7g</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767311786</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382686</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.02017</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>7.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>1.12054kotwiczka 4 gunsmoke</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>10.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767310581</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382863</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>10</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>1.12054</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>8.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>1.12055kotwiczka 2 gunsmoke</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>10.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767310598</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382867</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>10</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>1.12055</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>9.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.01014Gł.jig 7g hacz 2/0</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767315210</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382182</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.01014</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>10.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.01016Gł.jig 7g hacz 4/0</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767315234</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382202</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.01016</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>11.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.01017Gł.jig 7g hacz 5/0</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767315241</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382210</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.01017</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
    <data>
        <z1Lpf1>12.00</z1Lpf1>
        <z1NazwaLubOpisf1>3.04005Gł jig żół blaszka 6g</z1NazwaLubOpisf1>
        <z1Iloscf1>5.00</z1Iloscf1>
        <z1Jmf1>opak.</z1Jmf1>
        <z1KodKreskowyf1>5902767311847</z1KodKreskowyf1>
        <z1Wlasne1f1>382695</z1Wlasne1f1>
        <z1Wlasne2f1>5</z1Wlasne2f1>
        <z1SymbolTowaruf1>3.04005</z1SymbolTowaruf1>
    </data>
</FormattedReport>
```

[image: Imported Access Table]

Comment: I try this but I have error.
Run-time error '31593':
MS Access encountered an error while processing the XML schema in the OutputXML.xml file

The document must contain exactly one root element

Comment: You actually have an undeclared namespace prefix in root: `urn:crystal-reports:schemas`. So your *Output.xml* is blank. I have adjusted XSLT to account for this. By the way, you can load your XML directly from URL. See updated VBA using your posted link.

Comment: It's work!!
 I tried XSLT but I have this error and I don't now why :).
Big THANKS for help !!!